# Postgresql: can I join colums with the same name in a materialized view?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I use this query to join two tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM horses h
RIGHT JOIN races r ON h.racedate = r.racedate 
                   AND h.racename = r.racename 
                   AND h.racetime = r.racetime 
ORDER BY r.racedate, r.racetime
```

This works without a problem, but if I try:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW allracesview AS
    SELECT *
    FROM horses h
    RIGHT JOIN races r ON h.racedate = r.racedate 
                       AND h.racename = r.racename 
                       AND h.racetime = r.racetime
    ORDER BY r.racedate, r.racetime DESC
```

I get the error

> ERROR: FEHLER:  Spalte »racetime« mehrmals angegeben

Which means "Column racetime is specified multiple times" and only 3 columns are added to the view.

How can I join these two tables in a materialized view?

Comment: That error would make sense if your MView also contained the `select *` - did you show us the real code?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you only pick columns from the `races` table in the MVIEW, so you could get rid of the (somewhat costly) DISTINCT and replace the `right join` with an EXISTS condition. But the right join seems rather strange anyway to be honest - why not just select from `races` directly. I would expect you can't have a race without a horse (which is what the right join seems to assume)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I edited the code so it is a simple copy of the first one - i get the same error as above statet. What is the reason for this? - oh and I try it using pg admin4

Comment: Well, the error message is clear in that case. `select *` return all columns of all tables. As you have the same columns in both table, you have duplicated column names in the result. This is OK for a simple SELECT statement, but in a table, view or mview all column names must be unique. Replace the dreaded `select *` with an explicit column list.

Comment: Oh lord, that will be a lot of columns (80+) But many thanks 

Answer (score 1):

Like @a_horse_with_no_name said in the comments, `select *` does return all columns of all tables. As you have the same columns in both tables, you have duplicated column names in the result.

> How can I join these two tables in a materialized view? Without an explicit column list?

You can use a `USING` clause for the `JOIN` condition. [The output of JOIN USING` suppresses redundant columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html), so go with

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW allracesview AS
    SELECT *
    FROM horses 
    RIGHT JOIN races USING (racedate, racename, racetime)
    ORDER BY racedate, racetime DESC
```